# How do I disable the popup, when using Android startLockTask() method?

Tags: android, maui, kiosk-mode

I am using the Android `startLockTask()` method to enable a kind of soft kiosk mode on the device. However, every time the LockTask starts, a very annoying popup is displayed to the user with the info on how to turn off the LockTask:

[image]

I would like to start the LockTask without this popup. Is it possible (without going the whole root, or device admin route)?

I am using .NET MAUI specifically, is that makes any difference in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible without rooted device.

Documentation also mentions popup appearance:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startLockTask()

Comment: I do not see anything about a popup appearance in the documentation... Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @ŠtěpánObrátil: Quoting the documentation: "In this case, the system will prompt the user with a dialog requesting permission to use this mode. The user can exit at any time through instructions shown on the request dialog."

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, I know that, that is the whole point of my question. Not sure how your comment provides any answer. Is there actually a way to at least modify the popup?

Comment: @ŠtěpánObrátil: "yes, I know that" -- not according to your first comment, where you wrote "I do not see anything about a popup appearance in the documentation... Can you point me in the right direction?". So, I pointed you to the relevant passage in the documentation. "Is there actually a way to at least modify the popup?" -- for security reasons, I certainly hope not.

Comment: @CommonsWare The quoted part of the documentation doesn't seem relevant to "popup appearance". Just mentions that the popup appears, which is kind of the whole issue here.

Comment: @ŠtěpánObrátil: "Just mentions that the popup appears" -- in your first comment, you asked about "a popup appearance", and so it is reasonable to interpret that you asked about when and how "the popup appears". My current guess is that by "a popup appearance", you really meant "how to control what the popup looks like".

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah I see the confusion now :) Yes, by appearance I meant the way it looks, not the act of appearing.